# PyQt: QPushButton Stretch to Equal Size

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a grid of buttons from 1 to 42. Some of the buttons I want split into two (blue/pink) and some as a single button (green). I want the green area to be the same size as the blue/pink areas combined. When I remove the setSizePolicy on ItemButton1 & ItemButton2, i get the results I want, but the buttons became really small and does not fill the whole area. How can I get the areas to be equal and buttons to be expanded?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets,QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class FormWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FormWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.grid = QGridLayout(self)

        itemNumber = 0
        final = ['a1,1,,', 'a2,2,,', 'a3,3,,', 'a4,4,,', 'a5,5,,', 'a6,6,,', 'a7,7,,', 'a8,8,,', 'a9,9,,', 'a10,,10,28',
          'a11,,11,29', 'a12,,12,30', 'a13,,13,31', 'a14,,14,32', 'a15,,15,33', 'a16,,16,34', 'a17,,17,35',
          'a18,,18,36', 'a19,,19,37', 'a20,,20,38', 'a21,,21,39', 'a22,,22,40', 'a23,,23,41', 'a24,,24,42',
          'a25,,25,43', 'a26,,26,44', 'a27,,27,45', 'a28,1,,', 'a29,1,,', 'a30,1,,', 'a31,1,,', 'a32,1,,', 'a33,1,,',
          'a34,1,,', 'a35,1,,', 'a36,1,,', 'a37,1,,', 'a38,1,,', 'a39,1,,', 'a40,1,,', 'a41,1,,','a42,1,,']

        for i in range(1, 12, 2):
            for k in range(0, 7):
                getData = str(final[itemNumber]).split(',')
                self.PrimaryComboLabel = QLabel()
                self.PrimaryComboLabel.setText(getData[0])
                print(getData)
                if getData[1].strip() == '':
                    frame = QFrame()
                    frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(200, 255, 255)")
                    self.grid.addWidget(frame, k, i, 1, 1)
                    frame2 = QFrame()
                    frame2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 150, 255)")
                    self.grid.addWidget(frame2, k, i + 1, 1, 1)
                    self.grid.addWidget(self.PrimaryComboLabel, k, i, 1, 2, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                    self.ItemButton1 = QPushButton('')
                    self.grid.addWidget(self.ItemButton1, k, i, 1, 1)
                    self.ItemButton1.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
                    self.ItemButton1.setFlat(True)
                    self.ItemButton2 = QPushButton('')
                    self.grid.addWidget(self.ItemButton2, k, i + 1, 1, 1)
                    self.ItemButton2.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
                    self.ItemButton2.setFlat(True)
                else:
                    frame = QFrame()
                    frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0)")
                    self.grid.addWidget(frame, k, i, 1, 2)
                    self.grid.addWidget(self.PrimaryComboLabel, k, i, 1, 2, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                    self.PrimaryComboLabel.setScaledContents(True)
                    self.ItemButton3 = QPushButton('')
                    self.grid.addWidget(self.ItemButton3, k, i, 1, 2)
                    self.ItemButton3.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
                    self.ItemButton3.setFlat(True)

                itemNumber = itemNumber + 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = FormWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem seems to be the wrong type of QSizePolicy for your column width. Trying it with Preferred seems to do the trick:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets,QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class FormWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FormWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.grid = QGridLayout(self)

        itemNumber = 0
        final = ['a1,1,,', 'a2,2,,', 'a3,3,,', 'a4,4,,', 'a5,5,,', 'a6,6,,', 'a7,7,,', 'a8,8,,', 'a9,9,,', 'a10,,10,28',
          'a11,,11,29', 'a12,,12,30', 'a13,,13,31', 'a14,,14,32', 'a15,,15,33', 'a16,,16,34', 'a17,,17,35',
          'a18,,18,36', 'a19,,19,37', 'a20,,20,38', 'a21,,21,39', 'a22,,22,40', 'a23,,23,41', 'a24,,24,42',
          'a25,,25,43', 'a26,,26,44', 'a27,,27,45', 'a28,1,,', 'a29,1,,', 'a30,1,,', 'a31,1,,', 'a32,1,,', 'a33,1,,',
          'a34,1,,', 'a35,1,,', 'a36,1,,', 'a37,1,,', 'a38,1,,', 'a39,1,,', 'a40,1,,', 'a41,1,,','a42,1,,']

        for i in range(1, 12, 2):
            for k in range(0, 7):
                getData = str(final[itemNumber]).split(',')
                self.PrimaryComboLabel = QLabel()
                self.PrimaryComboLabel.setText(getData[0])
                print(getData)
                if getData[1].strip() == '':
                    frame = QFrame()
                    frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(200, 255, 255)")
                    self.grid.addWidget(frame, k, i, 1, 1)
                    frame2 = QFrame()
                    frame2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 150, 255)")
                    self.grid.addWidget(frame2, k, i + 1, 1, 1)
                    self.grid.addWidget(self.PrimaryComboLabel, k, i, 1, 2, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                    self.ItemButton1 = QPushButton('')
                    self.grid.addWidget(self.ItemButton1, k, i, 1, 1)
                    self.ItemButton1.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
                    self.ItemButton1.setFlat(True)
                    self.ItemButton2 = QPushButton('')
                    self.grid.addWidget(self.ItemButton2, k, i + 1, 1, 1)
                    self.ItemButton2.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
                    self.ItemButton2.setFlat(True)
                else:
                    frame = QFrame()
                    frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0)")
                    self.grid.addWidget(frame, k, i, 1, 2)
                    self.grid.addWidget(self.PrimaryComboLabel, k, i, 1, 2, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                    self.PrimaryComboLabel.setScaledContents(True)
                    self.ItemButton3 = QPushButton('')
                    self.grid.addWidget(self.ItemButton3, k, i, 1, 2)
                    self.ItemButton3.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
                    self.ItemButton3.setFlat(True)

                itemNumber = itemNumber + 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = FormWidget()
    ex.resize(750,100)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I resized the main window to some constants, you may want to change that based on your needs.